# How to use EC2 instance after detaching load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

As the traffic is got very low, How can I detach the load balancer and get the traffic routed directly to my EC2 instance?

Currently, I have my app URL as: myApp.elasticbeanstalk.com which points to the load balancer, how to make it point to the EC2 instance it self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove the existing record which points to your ELB.
- Create a A record for **myapp.elasticnbeanstalk.com** and points it to
  EC2 Elastic / Public IP Address.

Make sure to use Elastic IP when you have only one EC2 since it doesn't change after stop/start.

Comment: The OP cannot create such an A record since he does not control the elastibeanstalk.com domain (Amazon does). He will have to create a different A record for his own domain.

Comment: @Vikash would the ec2 instance get removed if I deleted the elastic beanstalk app?